# Implementing a counter on function returning files from gdrive

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to implement a counter which keeps track of the number of times a file is downloaded. The function retrieves files from the google drive and it is printed on to the screen using for loop. Please help with a logic where to implement the counter to keep track of the count.

The function is as follows:

```
function makeRequest() {
      var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list();
    request.execute(function(resp) {          
        for (i=0; i<resp.items.length; i++) {
            var titulo = resp.items[i].title;
            var fechaUpd = resp.items[i].modifiedDate;
            var userUpd = resp.items[i].lastModifyingUserName;
            var userEmbed = resp.items[i].embedLink;
            var userAltLink = resp.items[i].alternateLink;
            var download = resp.items[i].webContentLink;
            var hold="Download";
            var flag=0;

           <!-- var fileInfo = document.createElement('li');
          <!--  fileInfo.appendChild(document.createTextNode('TITLE: ' + titulo + ' - LAST MODIF: ' + fechaUpd + ' - BY: ' + userUpd +'  url:  ' + hold.link(download)));                
           <!-- document.getElementById('content').appendChild(fileInfo);

            document.write(titulo + "&nbsp;");
            document.write(hold.link(download) + "<br>");
            <!--flag=1;
            }

            <!--if(flag!=1){
            <!--document.write("not found!");
            <!--}
    });  ;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you want to keep track off.
If you want to a single user to be able to see how many times that user has downloaded a file, it could be implemented in javascript and store the information in a cookie.

If you on the other hand want to see how many times a file has been downloaded by any user, it has to be implemented on the server side using PHP or whatever language you have available.

The key question here is if you can/want to implement the functions on the server or the client side. To do it on the client side you use javascript, to do it on the server side you can use PHP.

Comment: I want to keep track of how many times a single file has been downloaded. See this function is printing out the file name and its download link. How can i implement a counter in PHP?